# Get UIImageView from UITabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

How to get imageView from `UITabBar` specific items.  From below code its highlight enter specific section View.

I need to highlight More Tab only `UIImageView` for CoachMark.

How to get UIImageView value from UITabBar ?

```
        guard let view = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.last?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else{
            return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark()
        }
       // let imageView = view.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIImageView }.first
       // return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: imageView) // Fails

        return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: view)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these extensions to your app.

```
import UIKit

public extension UITabBar {
    var tabBarButtons: [UIView] {
        let values = self.subviews.filter({ String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITabBarButton" })
        return values.sorted(by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x })
    }
}

public extension UIView {
    var tabBarSwappableImageViews: [UIView] {
        let values = self.subviews.filter({ String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITabBarSwappableImageView" })
        return values.sorted(by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x })
    }
}
```

Then call this on your tab bar controller

```
let imageView: UIImageView? = UITabBarController?.tabBar.tabBarButtons[YOUR_INDEX_HERE].tabBarSwappableImageViews.first
```

Comment: For first index its perfectly worked.  But when used second index its failing return empty array.  
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tabBarButtons[1].tabBarSwappableImageViews ▿ Optional<Array<UIView>> - some : 0 elements